# How to de-increment the order numbers column when an item is deleted from the list Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to de-increment the order numbers column for when an item is deleted from the list for example if there were 3 items and item 2 was deleted I want the order numbers to be 1 and 2 however it is showing as 1 and 3. I tried using a foreach to loop through the order numbers to do an update but I'm not having much success. Really appreciate the help thank you.

```
public function destroy(Images $image, Request $request)
{
        $image->delete();

        $image->update(['order' => 0]);

        $images = Images::all();
        
        foreach ($images as $img){
            $img->timestamps = false;
            $id = $img->id;

            foreach ($request->order as $order){
                if ($order['id'] == $id){
                    $img->update(['order' => $order['position']]);
                }
            }
        }

        return Redirect::back()->with('message','Image Deleted!');
}
```

Comment: Easiest and built-in way is : `$image->decrement('order'); ` no need any loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function destroy(Images $image, Request $request)
{
        $image->delete();

        $image->update(['order' => 0]);

        $images = Images::all();

        $i = 1;

        foreach ($images as $img){
            $img->timestamps = false;
            $id = $img->id;
            
            $img->update(['order' => $i]);
            $i++;
        }

        return Redirect::back()->with('message','Image Deleted!');
}
```